# How can I get a single file name by searching for the extension alone?

Tags: c#, file-io, filesystems

I'm using C# with WinForms and I want to get a single file name by searching for the extension alone? I know about the Directory.GetFiles Method, but I'm only looking for a single file. I'm currently using...

```
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\tpro", "*.fdn");
 string test = files.GetValue(0).ToString();
```

This works to get the name of the file that ends with .fdn. It works because it will only file in the directory that ends with .fdn. So using Index "0" in this case works.  But this just doesn't sit well with me. Is there a better way to go about it?

Thanks

Comment: what's wrong with it?  use string test = files.Length == 0 ? "" :files[0];  to tidy it up a bit.  Is that the issue?

Comment: I knew there must be something I was doing wrong. And as SLaks says, I'm misusing the array. Thanks to his help I'll have better code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No; this is the only sane way to do it.
However, you're misusing the array; you should write `string test = files[0]`.

In .Net 4.0, you can use the iterator version to avoid fetching more files than needed:

```
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\tpro", "*.fdn");
string test = files.First();
```

This will be much faster for enormous directories.

Comment: Thanks SLaks. I like the .NET 4.0 tip too.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use linq by adding `using System.Linq;` to your file, and do:

```
string test = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\tpro", "*.fdn").FirstOrDefault();
```

Which will set `test` to the first found filename, or leave it `null` if no file was found.
Though this is basically the same as your original code, except that your original code will throw an exception if there are no matched files.